# How to correctly set up a istream& operator>> for an array item?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I have a dynamically made queue, and I'm trying to overload the >> operator for it. But the number I enter is wrong. Any guesses on what I'm doing wrong? (the << operator works just fine though). 
So my class is:

```
class queue
{
     int queue1[100];
     int rear1,front1, num1;
public:
    queue(): rear1(-1),front1(-1){};
    queue(int , int , int);

    void insert1(int );
    void delet1();

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, queue& obj);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const queue& obj);
    void queue::printOn(ostream &out) const;

};
```

and the function operator itself:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, queue& obj){
    in >> obj.queue1[obj.rear1++];
    cout <<"inserted: " << obj.queue1[obj.rear1];
    return(in);
}
```

and my main funtion is:

```
queue qu1;
cout<<"Entered number:";
cin>>qu1;
cout << qu1;
```

This is how the program works:

> Entered number: 5

but

> inserted: -858993460
>
> inserted: -858993460

Comment: you are printing the object after the last element since you have done `rear1++`. You should use `cout <<"inserted: " << obj.queue1[obj.rear1-1];`

Comment: Why do you call out "correctly" in the (already very long) question title? What does that add?

Comment: Yeah, that helped, and it prints out the number I entered. But when I try to print out the queue like so:
`cout<<qu1;`
 it still prints out the -858993460 number.

Comment: you do not give us your `operator <<` implementation

Comment: yup, your advise solved the problem, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj.rear1++` will return the current `real1`,

---

so in first time use

`in >> obj.queue1[obj.rear1++];` becomes `in >> obj.queue1[-1];`

this is undefined behavior.

`cout <<"inserted: " << obj.queue1[obj.rear1];` becomes `cout <<"inserted: " << obj.queue1[0];`

this read from uninitialized memory, also undefined behavior.

---

change `obj.rear1++` to `++obj.rear1` can solve these two problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined behavior:

```
in >> obj.queue1[obj.rear1++];
cout <<"inserted: " << obj.queue1[obj.rear1];  << rear1 is 1 more than above
```